# How to use regex to remove substring from beginning of a string based on a condition in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this

```
term = "Hey there how you doing?"
```

Now because of some issues in the API, I sometimes receive undefined in the beginning of the string.

```
term = "#0undefinedHey there how you doing?"
```

OR

```
term = "#1undefined Hey there how you doing?"
```

Now I can check the presence of `undefined` in the beginning of the sentence by doing something like

```
if(term.indexOf("undefined") == 0) {
    //processing logic
}
```

But as you can see there is a presence of `#n` with the `undefined` where `n` can be any single digit number.

I want a regex solution such that it ignores `#n` and looks for `undefined` in the beginning of the sentence and remove the `#n` and `undefined`.

So the final string if `undefined` is present will be

```
term = "Hey there how you doing?" // removed #nundefined
```

How can I do this with regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let s = "#0undefined Hello World!";
console.log(s.replace(/^\#[0-9]*undefined\s*/,''));

const regex = RegExp('^\#[0-9]*undefined');
console.log('Has undefined = ' + regex.test(s));
```

Comment: Hey is there a way to put a condition check first and then do the replacement? I need to add some logic once I identify such scenario.

Comment: Added the regex to get true/false if it contains the undefined junk.

Answer (score 1):

If this number next to `undefined` makes any sense to you, you can try:

```js
const matches = "#1undefined Hey there how you doing?".match(/#([0-9]*)undefined ?(.*)/);
console.log(matches);
```

This will give you the number under `matches[1]` while your cleaned message will be at `matches[2]`.

---

If you just care about the message, you can use `.replace` as another user suggested to clean your output:

```js
const output = "#1undefinedHey there how you doing?".replace(/#([0-9]*)undefined ?/, '');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: @Michallis your code will also give a match if I put `#1undefined` at the end of the sentence.